# C++ OS X open default browser

Tags: c++, macos, url, browser

I would like to know a way to open the default browser on OS X from a C++ application and then open a requested URL.

EDIT: I solved it like this:

```
system("open http://www.apple.com");
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In case you prefer using the native OS X APIs instead of `system("open ...")`

You can use this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <CoreFoundation/CFBundle.h>
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

using namespace std;

void openURL(const string &url_str) {
  CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithBytes (
      NULL,                        // allocator
      (UInt8*)url_str.c_str(),     // URLBytes
      url_str.length(),            // length
      kCFStringEncodingASCII,      // encoding
      NULL                         // baseURL
    );
  LSOpenCFURLRef(url,0);
  CFRelease(url);
}

int main() {
  string str("http://www.example.com");
  openURL(str);
}
```

Which you have to compile with the proper OS X frameworks:

```
g++ file.cpp -framework CoreFoundation -framework ApplicationServices
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the docs for [Launch Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html).